# Why does the super key display the symbol ⎄? Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

By default, all binds in ubuntu are associated with the super (windows) key. And about two hours ago the binds stopped working, and the super key now displays the ⎄ symbol. Now when I write the code and I need to change the language, it prints ⎄. Naturally, binds do not work now, do not change the language, do not minimize the windows. This is my first question here¸ so don't throw your slippers.

Comment: Did you change the keyboard layout?

Comment: No, I calmly wrote the code, then I realized that the key does not work, well, more precisely, it typing this symbol when i press superkey

Comment: What "binds" don't work?  Does this only happen in a particular application?  What keyboard layout are you using?  Did you restart the device?

Comment: I rebooted my laptop.It happens all the time.
All binds associated with the superkey do not work.
For example, when I write something and want to change the language, when I click on super and a space, then I get this sign ⎄

Comment: It sounds to me like you are activating a keyboard shortcut to change the keyboard layout. You did not answer about your current keyboard layout. I suggest that you review the keyboard layout settings and the keyboard shortcut settings.

Comment: I have English and Russian layouts. But it's not just about changing the layout. When I print something and for example I want to go to the desktop (Super+D), then again it does not work for me, instead, It just print the symbol and letter D -> ⎄d

Comment: It's ok. I will listen to your advice, I have already found an alternative to binds. I will wait until someone can solve this problem. Thank you for trying to help me!